# JSON can't get data from one Facebook page only

Tags: php, html, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm setting up a website that loads the number of likes from several facebook pages (hundreds). I'm using json query for this purpose.
Everything is perfectly working, except for just one page. [This](https://www.facebook.com/pages/VIVA-VOCE-die-a-cappella-Band/303612927736) page. Why?

In the code here: A works, B doesn't

```
<?php
  $fblikeA  = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/270129920400'))->{'likes'};
  $fblikeB  = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/303612927736'))->{'likes'};
  echo '"None of the Above" likes = '.$fblikeA.'<br>';
  echo '"Viva Voce" likes = '.$fblikeB.'<br>';
?>
```

I tried it on an external php compiler and there it was perfectly working, so it may be a problem of my server.

What would you say about it?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

The thing is `file_get_contents` is not recommended as it could fail several times while requesting too many things.

So, instead you should use curl. You can use the following function directly:

```
function GetJSONFromCurl($url)
{    
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   $JSON = curl_exec($ch);
   return $JSON;
}
```

And use it just like this:

```
$fblikeA  = json_decode(GetJSONFromCurl('http://graph.facebook.com/270129920400'))->{'likes'};
```

That's it!

Comment: I don't know how to use it. Should I set $url = graph.fb.com/ID ? How can I request the likes number? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini, you can add this lines if not exists:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_fopen = On
```